# ActionBarSherlock ListNavigationMode not working pre honeycomb

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am using actionbarsherlock and cannot get drop down navigation (list mode) working for api < 3.0. It works fine for newer devices, but for <3.0 the I cannot click on the spinner. The first entry shows up, but the drop down will not show up on click. Everything else with the action bar is fine, but I cannot get the drop down to function.

Anyone encounter a similar problem?

Comment: Paste the code in onCreate where you set the ListNavigation mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the problem, the issue was that I was using the wrong parent for "actionDropDownStyle". Using the parent below fixed the problem.

```
<style name="DropDownStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
     <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/gray3</item> 
</style>
```